Find the optimal solutions to a system of linear equations?
I have a linear optimization problem $\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{x} < \mathbf{0}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is a particular square matrix for my application, and $\mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{0}$.
I want to compute the set of minimal integer solutions.  That is, the set of all $\mathbf{x}$ where: (a) $\mathbf{x}$ satisfies the equation, (b) $\mathbf{x}$ has integer entries, and (c) no strictly smaller integer solution exists.
Formally, I can write these criteria as $$\min_{\substack{\mathbf{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{N}^k}\\\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{x} <\mathbf 0}} (x_1,\ldots,x_n).$$
My question is: How do I generate these minimal solutions?
For background, I know that this is technically a "multiobjective pareto optimization", and I have seen (really computationally intensive) general-purpose algorithms for finding the solutions. But the problem structure is so simple—the domain is defined by a linear constraint, and the function being optimized is the identity—that I can't help but wonder if there is a more efficient way to compute the solution, or tighter bounds on the solution space, or compute the frontier for subproblems and combine them efficiently.
I have previously asked a similar question at Finding the Pareto frontier when the optimization problem is simple?.

Binary variables
I will start with the case where all $x$'s are binary variables, i.e., $x_i \in \{0,1\}$, as that is a simpler special case.  Here is the best algorithm I know of, for that problem.
To find one minimal solution, use an ILP solver to minimize $\mathbf{1}^\top \cdot \mathbf{x}$ subject to $\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{x} < \mathbf{0}$, $\mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{0}$.  Here $\mathbf{1}^\top$ represents the vector where every entry is 1.  Any solution to this will be a minimal solution for your original problem.
To find all minimal solutions, repeat the following until the problem becomes infeasible (no more solution remain): find one minimal solution, call it $\mathbf{x}^*$, using the above procedure; add the inequality $(1-\mathbf{x}^*)\cdot \mathbf{x}>0$ (i.e., $(\mathbf{x}^*-1)\cdot \mathbf{x}<0$) to the set of inequalities; and repeat.
Why does this work?  The key observation is that $(1-\mathbf{x}^*) \cdot \mathbf{x}>0$ iff $\mathbf{x}$ is not strictly smaller than $\mathbf{x}^*$.  Therefore, at each step, we find one more minimal solution $\mathbf{x}^*$, then add a constraint that all future solutions must not be strictly smaller than this $\mathbf{x}^*$.
Integer variables
I believe we can generalize this to the case where $x$'s can be arbitrary non-negative integers, as long as they are known to be upper-bounded by some constant $M$, but it gets messier.  Instead of adding the inequality $(1-\mathbf{x}^*)\cdot \mathbf{x}>0$, do the following.  Introduce a new vector of binary variables $\mathbf{t}$, and add the inequalities $x_i \ge (x^*_i + 1) t_i$ and $\mathbf{1}^\top \cdot \mathbf{t} \ge 1$.  Then apply the above procedure.  Unfortunately the number of variables grows at each step, so it will be slower.
